# Как получить и сохранить в HashMap<String, String> содержимое файла properties в Java?

Tags: java, map, properties

Добрые день. Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(inputStream);
```

Вот дошел до этого момента.
Как теперь получить пары ключ:значение при условии, что у меня уже есть Map  и мне нужно в него сохранить, но типизацию нельзя менять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс Properties это наследник Hashtable. Следовательно вы может либо использовать его, либо скопировать все значения в новый Map

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry: p.entrySet()) {
    map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: @Gerltsx я исправил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

используя возможности java 8:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(inputStream);
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();    
p.forEach((k, v) -> {map.put((String) k, (String) v);});
```